# Why must database name be specified in AbstractMongoClientConfiguration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb it specifies that `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` implement `String getDatabaseName()`. Furthermore, this implementation is mandatory. I found this inconvenient to have to manage the database name property in the implementation when all I want to do is override something else (e.g. `configureConverters()`). Is there a reason `getDatabaseName()` could not have a default implementation in `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` where the `MongoProperties` could be injected and used to derive the database name? I considered raising an issue on github, but noticed there's no "Issues" tab, so asking here.